# AngularJS loop through nested JSON array and make $http request with the result

Tags: angularjs

I have an `$http` request going out and fetching some JSON that is being returned in a structure like this:

```
{
  "news": [
    {
      "item1": "information1",
      "item2": "information2",
      "item3": "information3",
      "itemId": "ID1"
    },
    {
      "item1": "information1",
      "item2": "information2",
      "item3": "information3",
      "itemId": "ID2"
    },
    {
      "item1": "information1",
      "item2": "information2",
      "item3": "information3",
      "itemId": "ID3"
    },
  ]
}
```

Now, I can use `ng-repeat` to get to the news items just fine, but I need to make another `$http` request with the ID that is nested in each news item. Basically, I need to use that ID to find a name so that my news items are no longer just bits of information with an ugly ID, but bits of information with a user-friendly name. I already have the code returning, what I think, is the ID for each of those news items:

```
$http.jsonp('http://website/api/news&jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK')
    .success(function (result) {
        $scope.news = result.news;

        $scope.items = [];
        angular.forEach(result.news, function (item, index) {
            $scope.items.push(item);

            $http.jsonp('http://website/api/' + $scope.items.itemId + '?jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK')
                .success(function (result) {
                    $scope.fullItem = result.data;
                })
                .error(function () {
                    $log.warn("Something broke.");
                });
        });
    })
    .error(function () {
        $log.warn("Something broke.");
    });
```

As always, any help you all could provide would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What actually you want to achieve? You can have $http call inside loop for each IDs.

Comment: Sounds good to me. I had been having issues with doing that, but maybe it was the loop that was constructed poorly.

Comment: Try that. If you got any error then post it. I'll help you.

Comment: Went ahead and updated my post with the `$http` including the loop and the second `$http` call. It doesn't actually look like it's trying the second `$http` call. Fiddler isn't picking up any chatter and I should be seeing quite a bit if it does one for each news item.

Comment: First thing I can see is off is the name spaced item.itemid in your json it's called ID not itemID. Second it's missing the $scope part as well...

Comment: @StenMuchow - Deleting my other two comments and consolidating: Okay, I amended the code in the example. itemId is indeed the correct name on both the JSON and the `$http` request. I also added `$scope` and it did make the connection. Not it's just telling me that `$scope.items.itemId` is coming back as undefined.